Get the row number and column name of blank cells using arrayformula
I have two column L,M from rows 4-9.
Now I am trying to check if cells under these columns are blank or not. And if the cell or cells are blank , the result cell should display blank cell's row number and column name.
For e.g. if cell at row 6 column L is blank, output should be "Row: 6, Column: L is blank".
So I have used the formula :
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(L5:L8)=TRUE,CONCATENATE("ROW: ",ROW(L5:M8)," COL: ",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN(L5:M8),4),"3","")),""))


However, when I use this formula I get an output like:

With the use of the above formula it is showing all the result in one cell.
The correct output should be -
Row:  5, Col : L
Row 5, Col : M
How do I update the formula so it gives the desired result?

You can use the ADDRESS function. The following formula returns the address of the blank cells in the range L5:M8.
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(L5:M8="",ADDRESS(ROW(L5:M8),COLUMN(L5:M8),4),))) 

Another solution using REDUCE:
=REDUCE(,L5:M8,LAMBDA(a,c,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,a,IF(c="",ADDRESS(ROW(c),COLUMN(c),4),))))


Thanks, this works absolutely well. Could you explain the address formula, if I use address(column(L5),4), I get $C$13 as output.

check out the link to the official documentation.


...output should be - Row: 6, Col: L is blank
The correct output should be - Row: 5, Col : L Row 5, Col : M

try:
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TOCOL(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(L4:M9="", 
 REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(ROW(L4:M9), COLUMN(L4:M9), 4), 
 "(.+)(\d+)", "ROW: $2, COL: $1,"), )),,9^9))), ",$", " is blank"))


or if it should be all in one cell:
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(TOCOL(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(L4:M9="", 
 REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(ROW(L4:M9), COLUMN(L4:M9), 4), 
 "(.+)(\d+)", "ROW: $2, COL: $1,"), )),,9^9)),,9^9)), ",$", " is blank"))



Thanks, how do I extend the formula for the whole sheet (same columns, n no of rows) but the formula should check till current date and previous dates ?

@alittlecurryhot can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?
